# How to map 1 table entity into multiple (2 or 3) different database table?

Tags: java, mysql, nhibernate-mapping

I am saving my data into a selected database with my default method. However, there is 1 entity that i want to save on different table's column. How should i change on my method?

LoginBean.java

```
private String fullName_;
private String gender_;
private String phoneNumber_;
private String IC_;
private String email_;
private String Address_;
private String password_;
private String course;

List<String> courseOption;

public LoginBean(){

courseOption = new ArrayList<>();
    courseOption.add("Information Technology");
    courseOption.add("Business Management");
    courseOption.add("Engineering");
    courseOption.add("Design");

//getter and setter

    public String saveUserStudent(LoginBean loginBean){
    UserDao dao = new UserDao(); 
    User user = new User();
    user.setFullName(loginBean.getFullName_());
    user.setGender(loginBean.getGender_());
    user.setPhoneNumber(Integer.parseInt(loginBean.getPhoneNumber_()));
    user.setIc(loginBean.getIC_());
    user.setEmail(loginBean.getEmail_());
    user.setAddress(loginBean.getAddress_());
    user.setPassword(loginBean.getPassword_());
    dao.saveUserStudent(user);

    Map<String,Object> sessionMapObj = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
        sessionMapObj.put("msg", "Data "+user.getIc() +"successfull!");
```

my dao.saveUserStudent(user) is the method name that has been saved on the directed database. Is there anything i should add or change on the source code?

Comment: The same way as you would without JSF and in a unit test (and PLEASE check your tagging, nhibernate is for .Net. And you should use jpa, not hibernate directly and... )

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: And please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209854/how-to-use-spring-dao-methods-with-managedbean-object (including both its duplicates)

Comment: and please format the code in a more readably way

Comment: @Kukeltje sorry for the poor writing, i have been starting to getting by with the forum around a week. Thank you for your feedback.