# Primefaces not showing data in tags

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm currently working on a CRUD app using Primefaces for the view. I did the same app without Primefaces and it worked perfectly but when I tried to implement the new view it won't display my messages anymore (producto.mensaje), it inserts, edits and deletes correctly into the database but it just won't show any of the messages, I eventually fixed the issue by displaying the message on another way using <p:messages /> in the .xhtml file and using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage() in the backing bean but I still would like to know why it didn't work the other way. Thanks.

Here's the .xhtml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>PrimeFaces</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="header">
            <!--
            <ui:include src="/header.xhtml" >
                   <ui:param name="param_name" value="param_value" />
            </ui:include>
            -->
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h:form id="form">
                <p:outputLabel value="PRODUCTO"/>
                <br></br><br></br>
                <p:outputLabel value="Código:"/>
                <p:inputText id="codigo" value="#{producto.codigo}" />
                <br></br>
                <p:outputLabel value="Nombre:"/>
                <p:inputText id="nombre" value="#{producto.nombre}"/>
                <br></br>
                <p:outputLabel value="Precio:"/>
                <p:inputText id="precio" value="#{producto.precio}"/>
                <br></br><br></br>
                <p:commandButton id="insertar" value="Insertar" action="#{producto.insertar}" >  </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton id="eliminar" value="Eliminar" action="#{producto.eliminar}" > </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton id="modificar" value="Modificar" action="#{producto.modificar}" > </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton id="buscar" value="Buscar" action="#{producto.buscar}" > </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton id="promedio" value="Promedio" action="#{producto.promedio}" > </p:commandButton>
                <br></br><br></br>
                <p:outputLabel value="#{producto.mensaje}"/>

            </h:form>
        </div>
        <!--Other solution--> 
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:messages id="mensajes" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" style="position: fixed;
                        top: 0px;
                        right: 0px;
                        width: 25%"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And here's the bean:

````
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

@ManagedBean()
@SessionScoped
public class producto {

    public String codigo = "";
    public String nombre = "";
    public String precio = "";
    public String mensaje = "";
    public float prom = 0;
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("lab_CRUD_PFPU");
    EntityManager em1 = factory.createEntityManager();

    public producto() {
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(String precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

    public void insertar() {
        String sql = "insert into producto (codigo,nombre, precio) values ('" + codigo + "'" + "," + "'" + nombre + "'" + "," + precio + ")";
        em1.getTransaction().begin();
        Query qe = em1.createNativeQuery(sql);
        try {
            qe.executeUpdate();
            em1.getTransaction().commit();
            //mensaje = "Se insertó satisfactoriamente";
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Se insertó satisfactoriamente", "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            em1.getTransaction().rollback();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No se insertó satisfactoriamente", "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));
        }

    }

    public void eliminar() {
        String sql = "delete from producto where codigo='" + codigo + "'";
        em1.getTransaction().begin();
        Query qe = em1.createNativeQuery(sql);

        int li_filas = qe.executeUpdate();
        if (li_filas >= 1) {
            em1.getTransaction().commit();
            //mensaje = "Se eliminó satisfactoriamente";
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Se eliminó satisfactoriamente", "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));

        } else {
            em1.getTransaction().rollback();
            //mensaje = "No se pudo eliminar";
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No se pudo eliminar", "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));
        }
    }

    public void modificar() {
        String sql = "update producto set nombre='" + nombre + "', precio=" + precio + " where codigo='" + codigo + "'";
        //String sql = "update vehiculo set marca='" + marca + "' where placa='" + placa + "'";
        em1.getTransaction().begin();
        Query qe = em1.createNativeQuery(sql);

        int li_filas = qe.executeUpdate();
        if (li_filas >= 1) {
            em1.getTransaction().commit();
            //mensaje = "Se actualizó satisfactoriamente";
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Se modificó satisfactoriamente", "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));

        } else {
            em1.getTransaction().rollback();
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No se pudo modificar", "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));
        }

    }

    public void buscar() {
        String sql = "select * from producto where codigo=" + "'" + codigo + "'";
        Query qe = em1.createNativeQuery(sql);
        List l1 = qe.getResultList();
        if (l1.size() >= 1) {
            Object[] ar_objeto = (Object[]) (l1.get(0));
            String ls_nombre = ar_objeto[1].toString();
            String ls_precio = ar_objeto[2].toString();
            nombre = ls_nombre;
            precio = ls_precio;
            mensaje = "";
        } else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No se pudo buscar el producto", "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));
        }

    }

    public void promedio() {
        String sql = "SELECT AVG(precio) from producto";
        Query qe = em1.createNativeQuery(sql);
        String aa = String.valueOf(qe.getSingleResult());
        mensaje = " Promedio: " + aa;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, mensaje, "Se insertó satisfactoriamente"));
    }
}```
````

Comment: try to add "update" attribute in commandbutton with "form:mensajes" as value

Comment: Off-topic but very relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao and use jsf 2.3 and cdi annotations

Comment: Off-topic but relevant too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463178/what-to-use-managed-beans-backing-beans-or-entity-beans